# A good synonym for persuasive?

Tags: synonyms

Preferably something that has a slight negative connotation since the character that is being described isn't the nicest person around. I've tried smarmy and slick, but those feel too "layman" for what I'm trying to go for here.

Much appreciated,

Andre.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. It will help to show what research you have done to find the desired term.

Comment: Please describe the character in some detail an explain why "smarmy" and "slick" feel too *layman*.  What do you mean by "layman"? Someone who is not an expert?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/persuasive

Answer (score 2):

A more formal equivalent to *smarmy* would be *unctuous*:

> : revealing or marked by a smug, ingratiating, and false earnestness or spirituality [[m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unctuous)]

And an alternative for *slick* would be *suave*:

> : smoothly though often superficially gracious and sophisticated [[m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suave)]

**Other possibilities**

*inveigling*:

> : winning over by wiles [adapted from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inveigle)]

*beguiling* [to me, this one seems closest to *persuasive*]:

> : engaging in the interest of by or as if by guile • His seductive voice *beguiled* the audience.
>   : leading by deception • *beguiled* into ambush
>   : deceiving by wiles • had intended to *beguile*
>     [all adapted from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beguile)]

*wheedling*:

> : influencing or enticing by soft words or flattery
>   : gaining or getting by wheedling • *wheedle* one's way into favor
>     [adapted from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wheedle)]

To me, all of these carry at least a whiff of negative connotation.

Comment: Definitions? That would improve the quality of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

**inveigle**:

> 1. Persuade (someone) to do something by means
>   of *deception* or flattery.
>       *‘we cannot inveigle him into putting pen to paper’*
>
> 1.1 (inveigle oneself" or "one's way into) Gain entrance to (a place) by using deception or flattery.
>   *‘Jones had inveigled himself into her house’*
>    <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inveigle)</sub>

> verb (used with object), inveigled, inveigling.
>
> 1. to entice, lure, or ensnare by flattery or artful talk or inducements
>   (usually followed by into): *to inveigle a person into playing bridge.*
>
> 2. to acquire, win, or obtain by beguiling talk or methods (usually
>   followed by from or away): *to inveigle a theater pass from a person*
>
> <sub>[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inveigle?s=t) Unabridged
>
>   Based on the Random House Dictionary, © Random House, Inc. 2018.</sub>

See also [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inveigle).

Comment: Looks like your link is messed up.

Comment: I'm not sure if you realized this, but your answer still had some problems (formatting, missing citation). I have taken the liberty of fixing it for you.

Comment: *Inveigle* is a great word, but it's not a synonym for *persuasive* because it's a different part of speech. @spoko already proposed *inveigling*, which is a bit of a stretch in my opinion, but at least could arguably replace *persuasive* in a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

### manipulative

> influencing or attempting to influence the behavior or emotions of
>   others for one’s own purposes
>
> http://www.dictionary.com/browse/manipulative
>
> ---
>
> serving or intended to control or influence others in an artful and often unfair or selfish way
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/manipulative

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest '**pushy**'.

> aggressive often to an objectionable degree : forward

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pushy)

> '**Pushy**’ Olympic official kicked out of South Korea ‘brought shame on Princess Anne’

[iNews 16th Feb 2018](https://inews.co.uk/news/pushy-olympic-official-kicked-south-korea-brought-shame-princess-anne-security-honcho-says/)

> **Pushy** man sends flowers to every pub in town after woman blocks him on Facebook

[iNews 4th Feb 2018](http://metro.co.uk/2018/02/04/pushy-man-sends-flowers-every-pub-town-woman-blocks-facebook-7286480/)